# Visual studio not removing app_offline.htm after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have a web application I've been working on with Visual Studio 2012. I've got several publishing profiles for different environments which are configured for file system publish.

Until yesterday all my code was located on one machine, but I got a new computer and copied those source files to the new machine.

Previously, my custom `app_offline.htm` would be pushed out during publishing and then be deleted afterwards.  Now, this isn't happening. The `app_offline.htm` file remains in the root of the web application preventing anybody from using the site.

Also, the build menu no longer says `"Publish <projectName>"` and just says `"Publish Selection"`.  I tried creating a new publishing profile with the same settings, manually editing the publishing profile files, cleaning and rebuilding the whole solution, and I've done a lot of reading but so far nobody seems to have had this same problem.  How can I get my publishing stuff to work again?

Comment: Do you have the same Visual Studio service packs, patches, etc. installed on your new machine that you did on the old?

Comment: Good question.  I didn't configure the new machine so I don't really know.  I either have the latest-and-"greatest" patches, or I have 0 patches.  I know I was behind an update or two on my old machine.

Comment: Do you still have the old machine?

Comment: It's around somewhere.  I'm applying update 4 to VS right now.

Comment: @BateTech you may consider suggesting the update thing as an answer.  Just saying ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same Visual Studio service packs, patches, etc. installed on your new machine that you did on the old? Try installing the latest Windows and Visual Studio updates and see if that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was.  There were no patches installed and putting Update 4 on it worked perfectly.